# Parsing gridline data and comparing with other data to get grid ranges

Tags: parsing, comparison, gridlines

I got one really challenging problem here. It is very important for me to solve this problem in order for our department to save millions (so sincere help is deeply appreciated).
Actually we have two different columns of "grid-line data" in text form. e.g. GL 23.5-24 / G. Here 23.5 - 24 represents the reading along X-axis while G represents the grind along Y-axis. All this data is in one column. Sometimes the data is not single value rather a combination of values e.g. GL 24-24.7 / S-T, GL 25.3-25.5 / S-T, and at sometimes it's like GL 27/H;27/H.5;26.5/J.5 and GL26.5-27.5/L.
Now I got two big challenges in working with this data.
First is that I have to convert this text-based data in to some sort of useful and directly understandable grid-line data i.e. GL 24-24.7 / S-T should be like 24 - 24.7 in one cell and S - T in other with clear indication that 24 - 24.7 is along X-axis and vice versa. After I do this then I have to COMPARE this data with another column having same type of data i.e. GL 24.5 / S.5. Comparison should be in a way that it tells me whether or not compared grids fall UNDER (as a subset) of main grid or not.
e.g. If i have main grid-line as 23 - 25 / R - T and I have the second grid is 24.5 / S then surely this second grid falls UNDER (or in between) the first one.

So the overall problem is about checking first grid line in other after separating the text data in useful grids. I did bit of scratch work only to get the parsing of overall strings but unable to form reasonable algorithm to proceed further.

Here is my current code to parse data.

```
Dim strAll() As String
Dim strSNO() As String, Meesam() As String
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer, newRng As Range, cnt As Integer, x As String
Dim a As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
 lastRow = .Range("A7000").End(xlUp).Row
 ReDim strAll(lastRow)
 Set newRng = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
End With

For cnt = LBound(strAll()) To UBound(strAll())
    strAll(cnt) = newRng.Cells(cnt + 1, 1).Value
Next

Do While i < UBound(strAll)

If (InStr(1, strAll(i), "Element", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
    i = i + 2
    Do Until InStr(1, strAll(50), "+GL", vbTextCompare) > 0 'Loop until line includes "+"
        Meesam = SplitMultiDelims(strAll(i), "/")
        a = 0
        For a = LBound(Meesam) To UBound(Meesam)
            newRng.Offset(i, a) = Meesam(a)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End If
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I know guys it's really complicated project But I'm sure there are lots of experts out there who can really manage it. I just need overall guideline and I will take care of the project myself. Thnx

Comment: I will be extremely happy even if anybody can share some general thoughts. My idea is to parse data based on "," values so that I get distinct grid data. Then main thing is to determine which value is higher i.e. B > A and so on (based on alphabets only). After all this i can use some comparison technique to compare with my reference list.

Comment: Guys I'm back with complete solution to the problem. It nearly took me one month to find final solution.

Comment: The function is given below and can be used in following way.
Cell A1 = Coordinates (as per the format in drawing) of AREA / LINE / POINT
Cell B1 = Coordinates (as per the format in drawing) of MAIN AREA
Cell C1 = IsInside(A1,B1)

Result will be "TRUE" if A1 falls within boundaries of B1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function IsInside(Area As String, Rectangle As String) As Boolean

Dim Parts() As String
Dim Line1 As String, Line2 As String, Lx1 As Single, Ly1 As Single, Lx2 As String, Ly2 As String
Dim Rect1 As String, Rect2 As String, Rx1 As Single, Ry1 As Single, Rx2 As String, Ry2 As String

On Error Resume Next

Parts = Split(Replace(Area, " ", ""), "/")
Line1 = Parts(0)
Line2 = Parts(1)

If InStr(1, Line1, "-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
 Parts = Split(Line1, "-")
 Lx1 = Parts(0)
 Ly1 = Parts(1)
Else
Lx1 = Line1
Ly1 = "0"
End If

If InStr(1, Line2, "-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
 Parts = Split(Line2, "-")
 Lx2 = Parts(0)
 Ly2 = Parts(1)
Else
Lx2 = Line2
Ly2 = 0
End If

Parts = Split(Replace(Rectangle, " ", ""), "/")
Rect1 = Parts(0)
Rect2 = Parts(1)

If InStr(1, Rect1, "-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
 Parts = Split(Rect1, "-")
 Rx1 = Parts(0)
 Ry1 = Parts(1)
Else
 Rx1 = Rect1
 Ry1 = 0
End If

If InStr(1, Rect2, "-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
 Parts = Split(Rect2, "-")
 Rx2 = Parts(0)
 Ry2 = Parts(1)
Else
 Rx2 = Rect2
 Ry2 = 0
End If

If Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 > 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 > 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 > 0 Then
 IsInside = Lx1 >= Rx1 And Lx1 <= Ry1 And Lx2 >= Rx2 And Lx2 <= Ry2
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 > 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 > 0 Then
 IsInside = Lx1 >= Rx1 And Lx1 <= Ry1 And Lx2 >= Rx2 And Ly2 <= Ry2
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 = 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 > 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 > 0 Then
 IsInside = Lx1 >= Rx1 And Lx1 <= Ry1 And Lx2 >= Rx2 And Lx2 <= Ry2
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 > 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 = 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 > 0 Then
 IsInside = 0
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 = 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 > 0 Then
 IsInside = Lx1 = Rx1 And Lx2 >= Rx2 And Ly2 <= Ry2
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 = 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 = 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 > 0 Then
 IsInside = Lx1 = Rx1 And Lx2 >= Rx2 And Lx2 <= Ry2
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 > 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 = 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 = 0 Then
 IsInside = 0
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 = 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 = 0 Then
 IsInside = 0
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 = 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 = 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 = 0 Then
 IsInside = 0
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 > 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 > 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 = 0 Then
 IsInside = 0
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 > 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 > 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 = 0 Then
 IsInside = 0
ElseIf Lx1 > 0 And Ly1 = 0 And Lx2 > 0 And Ly2 = 0 And Rx1 > 0 And Ry1 > 0 And Rx2 > 0 And Ry2 = 0 Then
 IsInside = 0
Else
End If

End Function
```

So all you have to do is put the grid value in one cell and the value of bigger rectangle (in which you have to search) in another cell and use the above mentioned function.